# Call SQL Server from a Linux Container without Passwords in the Connection String

Tags: linux, windows, containers, linux-containers

I am converting a service to run on a Linux Container.  Currently, the service runs in IIS in a Windows VM.

It runs as a Lan User that has permissions to the database.  Thus the connection string uses Integrated Security.

But Containers cannot join a domain.  So, as I understand it, that option is out.

I researched this for Windows Containers and found that it supports running as a Group Managed Service Account (gMSA) on the container host, and that calls made as "Network Service" are swapped to the gMSA.  (Allowing use of a domain user via the container host.)

But I cannot seem to find a similar feature for Linux containers.

**Do all processes run in Linux containers just put usernames and passwords in to their database connection strings?**

Or is there a better way to convey identity in a Linux Container?

To give a few more details on my particular setup:

- Running a Linux container
- Running .NET Core 2.2
- Running in Kubernetes (eventually)
- Database is Microsoft SQL Server Running on Windows

Comment: What do you mean by "Call" SQL Server? Are you using a specific client library to execute SQL queries? Are you using a CLI tool? It is likely that you can use environment variables for that. Especially when running kubernetes you can use secrets for credentials and mount them as files or environment variables to your pod. See https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#using-secrets-as-environment-variables and https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#using-secrets-as-environment-variables

Comment: @amazingTurtle - I mean using .NET Core to access the data in SQL Server using EF Core.  I will look into the k8s secrets concept.

Answer (score 0):

Would help to know a bit more of your setup, but with the information at hand there are 3 options as I could see.

- Option 1:

Manage the credentials with for docker secrets as per

https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/secrets/

```
docker container exec <CONTAINER_ID> \
bash -c 'mysqladmin --user=wordpress --password="$(< /run/secrets/old_mysql_password)" password "$(< /run/secrets/mysql_password)"'
```

- Option 2:

Depending on what kind of DB you're using you could add the password to the configuration, for example in my.conf for mysql.

```
[client]
password = 123
```

- Option 3:

Depending on your network stack, you could set the permissions in the database instead. Allowing the IP access to the database. But I would however recommend one of the other options.

Comment: It is not mysql it is sql server

Comment: This is the closest I can see to a way to manage this.  Basically it is to use an external system to try to track the secret for you.  .

Comment: The question is about SQL server, not MySQL, which is different. Moreover, it's one time password, so whenever the user has been created, the password need to be synced everytime it is changed between docker secret and the container. MS SQL has its own way (by using AD/Windows auth) to handle this, and this is not the close answer.

Answer (score 0):

So since it is a linux environment and I believe you want to use windows authentication you can use similar Ad authentication.

[Check here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-active-directory-authentication?view=sql-server-2017)

his tutorial explains how to configure SQL Server on Linux to support Active Directory (AD) authentication, also known as integrated authentication. For an overview, see Active Directory authentication for SQL Server on Linux.

This tutorial consists of the following tasks:

Join SQL Server host to AD domain
Create AD user for SQL Server and set SPN
Configure SQL Server service keytab
Secure the keytab file
Configure SQL Server to use the keytab file for Kerberos authentication
Create AD-based logins in Transact-SQL
Connect to SQL Server using AD Authentication

**update** I don't think windows domain integrated authentication can be used.I don't think there can be any integrated authentication then. try dsn so that your code does not have username password. https://www.easysoft.com/products/data_access/odbc-sql-server-driver/getting-started.html

Comment: I mistakenly left off the fact that SQL Server will be running on windows.  (SQL Server for Linux is still too new.)  Also, the container cannot join the domain... So how can it use integrated security?

Comment: I don't think there can be any integrated authentication then. try dsn so that your code does not have username password. https://www.easysoft.com/products/data_access/odbc-sql-server-driver/getting-started.html